# Where should my plugin POST to?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, security, forms

I'm creating a simple plugin to set a page as a homepage from the list pages (to appear next to edit, preview, trash actions etc), I was just wondering what that the most appropriate/secure place to submit this information to? By far the easiest way would be to just post back to the plugin file itself with a $_GET param, but that seems rather hacky and doesn't use a nonce or anything (my plugin does have `current_user_can()` in it.

Code is as simple as this:

```
function add_post_actions($actions, $post) {
    if($post->ID == get_option('page_on_front')) {
        $actions['homepage'] = '<span style="color: #999;">Your Homepage</span>';
    } else {
        $actions['homepage'] = '<a href="blah.php?post='.$post->ID.'">Set As Homepage</a>';
    }

    return $actions;
}

function change_to_homepage($postId) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to manage options for this site.' ) );

    update_option('show_on_front', 'page');
    update_option('page_on_front', $postId);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it makes sense to send via GET to the page you are currently on.

That way you just hook into `admin_init` and check for your GET variables.

As for security you can pass nonces via URLS: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url

Comment: Ok sounds easy, is there a WP function for getting/redirecting to the previous page? Also, would you check the `$_GET` then add the filter, or add the hook and check the `$_GET` in the function? Both require checking `$_GET` but only one adds a filter...